# Error: Cannot import wsdl:port with svcutil

Tags: .net, wcf, compiler-errors, svcutil.exe

I created a small WCF service (hosted in IIS) and used Chrome to take the wsdl of it, put that in a .wsdf file and then wanted to use `svcutil test.wsdl` to generate the client proxy out of it but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is depend
>   ent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/'
>   ]/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IService1']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/'
>   ]/wsdl:service[@name='Service1']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_IService1']

Anyone else encountered this and found a solution for it?

Update: as suggested by John Saunders, thanks for that, it works when I point it out directly to the url. However this is my little test case to see what svcutil can do as I expect the coming days to get a wsdl file from a 3rd party and might run into the same problem. As I took the most simplistic out of the box generated .svc I don't seem to be having include blocks.

Comment: I bet it told you exactly what problem it was having. Are you sure that's all the error output? Also, what happens when you specify the URL of the service directly to svcutil.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the wsdl has `Include` blocks in it - and they often do when generated by WCF - then you're likely only saving the 'main' wsdl file and not all the referenced files.

The result of this is that the main file won't make any sense.  As John Saunders suggests, try giving the URL to svcutil.exe instead of saving the file.

Comment: For any future searchers: I was having issue with the WSCF.blue plugin which was the same root cause. You can generate one-time proxies by manually assembling a WSDL by copying all included <schema> imports into the WSDL file. This didn't fix my problem (it's a lame workaround), but it was a helpful diagnostic trick to confirm where the problem was.

Comment: To follow up with my specific issue, I was specifying my import tag in the WSDL as follows: <xs:schema targetNamespace="mynamespace"><xs:import namespace="mynamespace" schemaLocation="myxsd.xsd"/></xs:schema>. WSCF.blue did not like having both targetNamespace in the schema tag and namespace in the import tag. Removing the namespace attribute from the import tag solved my tools problem.